# Update JFace treeviewer after changing the file directory

Tags: java, eclipse

Good day everyone. Currently working on an RCP project that involves using a treeviewer (org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer) to display a directory and the files in it in Eclipse. In essence, the tree is instantiated with a directory such as  `private String folderPath = "C:\\Default";` which works perfectly. It displays the initial directory and its contents perfectly after running the application.see image of treeviewer after running the RCP:

[image: see image of treeviewer after running the RCP]

The problem is when the folderpath is updated using a DirectoryDialog object, the treeviewer stays the same.

I'm finding it difficult to reinitialize the tree with the new value of folderpath while running the application..

Code attached here..

[treeviewer class](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ez5zfo67inpgrm7/SampleTreeView.java?dl=0)

```
        public class SampleTreeView extends ViewPart {

     private String folderPath = "C:\\Default";



     private TreeViewer tv;


     public SampleTreeView() {
      super();
     }

     public String getFolderPath() {


      return folderPath;
     }

     public void setFolderPath(String projectPath) {
      this.folderPath = projectPath;


     }

     public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
      Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
      composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

      // Add a check box to toggle whether the labels preserve case
      Button preserveCase = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
      preserveCase.setText("&Preserve case");

      Button refreshBtn = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
      refreshBtn.setText("Refresh");

      //register listener for the selection event
      refreshBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        tv.refresh();
       }
      });


      tv = new TreeViewer(composite);
      getSite().setSelectionProvider(tv);
      tv.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
      tv.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
      tv.setLabelProvider(new FileTreeLabelProvider());
      tv.setInput("root");

      preserveCase.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        boolean preserveCase = ((Button) event.widget).getSelection();
        FileTreeLabelProvider ftlp = (FileTreeLabelProvider) tv
         .getLabelProvider();
        ftlp.setPreserveCase(preserveCase);
       }
      });

     }

     public void setFocus() {
      tv.getControl().setFocus();
     }


     class FileTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {


      SampleTreeView stv = new SampleTreeView();

      File source = new File(stv.getFolderPath());

      public Object[] getChildren(Object arg0) {


       return ((File) arg0).listFiles();
      }


      public Object getParent(Object arg0) {

       return ((File) arg0).getParentFile();
      }


      public boolean hasChildren(Object arg0) {

       Object[] obj = getChildren(arg0);


       return obj == null ? false : obj.length > 0;
      }


      public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {

       return source.listFiles();
      }


      public void dispose() {

      }


      public void inputChanged(Viewer arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

      }
     }


     class FileTreeLabelProvider implements ILabelProvider {

      private List listeners;
      boolean preserveCase;



      public FileTreeLabelProvider() {

       listeners = new ArrayList();

      }


      public void setPreserveCase(boolean preserveCase) {
       this.preserveCase = preserveCase;


       LabelProviderChangedEvent event = new LabelProviderChangedEvent(this);
       for (int i = 0, n = listeners.size(); i < n; i++) {
        ILabelProviderListener ilpl = (ILabelProviderListener) listeners
         .get(i);
        ilpl.labelProviderChanged(event);
       }
      }


      public Image getImage(Object obj) {
       String imageKey = ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FILE;
       if (((File) obj).isDirectory())
        imageKey = ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER;
       return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(imageKey);
      }

      public String getText(Object arg0) {

       String text = ((File) arg0).getName();


       if (text.length() == 0) {
        text = ((File) arg0).getPath();
       }


       return preserveCase ? text : text.toUpperCase();
      }


      public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
       listeners.add(arg0);
      }

      public void dispose() {
       // Dispose the images
       if (dir != null)
        dir.dispose();
       if (file != null)
        file.dispose();
      }

      public boolean isLabelProperty(Object arg0, String arg1) {
       return false;
      }

      public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
       listeners.remove(arg0);
      }
     } //end of label provider
    }
```

Comment: Code you want us to look at must be included as a [mcve] in the question, not a link.

Comment: Alright. Will update now. Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing a `new SampleTreeView()` in the content provider? This is creating a new instance of the view which is unrelated to the actual view. In think you need to go back and read some tutorials on how content providers work with particular reference to `setInput` and `getElements`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the hint greg-449. Changes made. Any useful code snippet or links particular to the issue i sighted, accessing setInput etc will be appreciated.

Comment: It turns out that there was no need to pass `folderpath` directly to content provider to resolve the issue @greg-449. First, i had to setup  `folderpath` in  `Messages.java` and  `message.properties` for the plugin in question. The DirectoryDialog updates the `folderpath` entry in `Messages.java`. The refresh button resets the treeviewer to build the new directory and that resolves the issue. Hope this helps people in the future.